# Left Outer Join Vs Individual Queries DB2

Tags: sql, db2, mainframe

I am using Mainframe Db2. Its a patient database. My requirement is to fetch different information from 3 tables, TABACC, TABPAY and TABINS. TABACC will always have a row for a patient but TABPAY and TABINS may or may not have a row for a patient in the system.

Which will be more efficient, a QUERY on TABACC with LEFT OUTER JOIN to TABPAY and TABINS 
or three different queries, one for each TABACC, TABPAY and TABINS.

Comment: Do you realise patient means more than one thing? Unless you can intuit from TABACC that there will not be data on TABPAY and TABINS the JOIN will likely be more efficient. Set up a small program and test it out.

Comment: I need to get milk, eggs and bread from the store.  Is it more efficient to get a bag, go to the store and get all three items in a single trip, or make 3 separate trips to the store, each retrieving a single item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.

If all you doing is pulling back 1 row data from three tables, then it's hard to beat COBOL's random read.  There's simply less overhead.  SQL isn't magic.

But you mention writing out to a file.  So lets assume that you're pull back 100s, 1,000s or even millions of rows from those files and outputting them to a new file.

Instead of working row by row, which is COBOL's only option and all too often used when using SQL.  You could work with the entire set in SQL

```
insert into newtable 
  (SELECT TB1.COL1,
          TB2.COL4, 
          TB3.COL5, 
          TB4.COL6
  FROM TB1 JOIN TB2 ON TB1.KEY = TB2.KEY
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TB3 ON TB1.KEY = TB3.KEY
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TB4 ON TB1.KEY = TB4.KEY)
```

Now the SQL solution should be much, much faster.

The key with SQL is to think in sets.  If you are doing something row by row (aka using a cursor) you're probably (but not always) doing something wrong.

You can't simply change from COBOL's native I/O to SQL and expect better performance. It will in fact be worse.

Lastly, consider what the output file is being used for.  If you're exporting data to an outside system, then you're pretty much done.  But if you're writing a work file for another COBOL program to process...well you've probably got an opportunity for more improvement.  Look at the entire process, consider what's being done as a whole and how a set based SQL solution could do it.

Comment: I think OP is asking about one sql query with two joins vs the separate sql qeries. No native COBOL io at all.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right.  But it wouldnt' surprise me if there was originally a pure COBOL process with three native I/Os.  So I'll leave my answer out there.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put altogether. TB3, TB4 will return `NULL` if no rows found

```
SELECT TB1.COL1,
       TB2.COL4, 
       TB3.COL5, 
       TB4.COL6
FROM TB1 JOIN TB2 ON TB1.KEY = TB2.KEY
LEFT OUTER JOIN TB3 ON TB1.KEY = TB3.KEY
LEFT OUTER JOIN TB4 ON TB1.KEY = TB4.KEY;
```

Comment: Yes I know that I can write a single Query like you mentioned. But my question is will it be more effecient in terms of speed than writing 3 different queries and using their ouputs together. Since in COBOL I can fetch and keep the data in variables and then together write them into a file.

Comment: I would go for joins rather than three SQLs

Answer (score 0):

If the columns on which you are joining are indexed then that is the more efficient method.

Comment: Even when they are not indexed, then joining is most likely more efficient.